# Bootstrap. What's controlling where the form is sent?

Tags: html, forms

I am using Bootstrap with forms. How the "method=" or "action="?
What is telling it what to do/where to go? Should there be a "method"?
What's controlling where the form is sent?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>   
<html lang="en">   
<head>   
<meta charset="utf-8">   
<title>my form</title>   
<meta name="description" content="title page.">   
<link href="twitter-bootstrap-v2/docs/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">  
</head>  
<body>  
<form class="well">  
  <label>test page</label>  
  <input type="text" class="span3" placeholder="Type something…">   
  <label class="checkbox">  
  input type="checkbox"> Remember me
  </label>  
  <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>  
</form>  
</body>  
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question has nothing to do with bootstrap. Those are form tag attributes.

Refer : [Form_Tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp)

`action` Specifies where to send the form-data when a form is submitted

`method` Specifies the HTTP method to use when sending form-data. Default `method` is `GET`.

Example : `<form action="next_page.html" method="get">`

**Notes on GET:**

- Appends form-data into the URL in name/value pairs
- The length of a URL is limited (about 3000 characters)
- Never use GET to send sensitive data! (will be visible in the URL)
- Useful for form submissions where a user want to bookmark the result
- GET is better for non-secure data, like query strings in Google

**Notes on POST:**

- Appends form-data inside the body of the HTTP request (data is not shown is in URL)
- Has no size limitations
- Form submissions with POST cannot be bookmarked

Comment: I am quite new to this...Using the example given, how would I implement these.? Can you give an example using the code that I have posted.?

Comment: You can simply make two html pages, one with a form and the second one to display the data received. (Bootstrap is not required for this)

Comment: I need to make the form "responsive" on multiple devices, so I want to use Bootstrap. I already know how to use forms in normal html but need to know how to modify the code so that  can use bootstrap.

Comment: If you do know how to use forms this question is irrelevant. As your question asks what is method & action in the form tag.

Comment: You just want to make the form responsive?

Comment: yes, using bootstrap, but am not sure about how the form syntax differs from using normal html. Basically what needs to be added to the form.

Comment: Just use the usual form in bootstrap. Change the classes as you want for the responsiveness.